# Does anybody recognize this sequence of integer polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, pattern-recognition

The following sequence of polynomials with positive integer coefficients arises in a physics problem related to the quantum harmonic oscillator:

\begin{align}
p_{0}(x) &= 1 \\
p_{1}(x) &= x+1 \\
p_{2}(x) &= x^2+2 x+2 \\
p_{3}(x) &= x^3+3 x^2+8 x+6 \\
p_{4}(x) &= x^4+4 x^3+20 x^2+32 x+24 \\
p_{5}(x) &= x^5+5 x^4+40 x^3+100 x^2+184 x+120 \\
p_{6}(x) &= x^6+6 x^5+70 x^4+240 x^3+784 x^2+1104 x+720 \\
p_{7}(x) &= x^7+7 x^6+112 x^5+490 x^4+2464 x^3+5488 x^2+8448 x+5040 \\
p_{8}(x) &= x^8+8 x^7+168 x^6+896 x^5+6384 x^4+19712 x^3+52352 \
x^2+67584 x+40320
\end{align}

There are some interesting patterns in their coefficients, but despite my best efforts (and numerous OEIS lookups) I haven't been able to pin down a closed form or recurrence relation. Does anybody see one of these (or a similar nice characterization of $p_n$)?

The coefficients of $p_0, \dots, p_{30}$, which are too big to be nicely $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$'ed, are provided in the following table:

```
+---+----+------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1 |    |      |        |          |           |             |               |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  1 |      |        |          |           |             |               |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  2 |    2 |        |          |           |             |               |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  3 |    8 |      6 |          |           |             |               |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  4 |   20 |     32 |       24 |           |             |               |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  5 |   40 |    100 |      184 |       120 |             |               |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  6 |   70 |    240 |      784 |      1104 |         720 |               |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  7 |  112 |    490 |     2464 |      5488 |        8448 |          5040 |                |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  8 |  168 |    896 |     6384 |     19712 |       52352 |         67584 |          40320 |                  |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 |  9 |  240 |   1512 |    14448 |     57456 |      229760 |        471168 |         648576 |           362880 |                   |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 10 |  330 |   2400 |    29568 |    144480 |      804320 |       2297600 |        5360256 |          6485760 |           3628800 |                     |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 11 |  440 |   3630 |    55968 |    325248 |     2393600 |       8847520 |       30633856 |         58962816 |          74972160 |            39916800 |                      |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 12 |  572 |   5280 |    99528 |    671616 |     6296576 |      28723200 |      136804096 |        367606272 |         782525952 |           899665920 |            479001600 |                       |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 13 |  728 |   7436 |   168168 |   1293864 |    15027584 |      81855488 |      510205696 |       1778453248 |        5561407488 |         10172837376 |          12174658560 |            6227020800 |                         |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 14 |  910 |  10192 |   272272 |   2354352 |    33141680 |     210386176 |     1656182528 |       7142879744 |       30459752960 |         77859704832 |         154594381824 |          170445219840 |             87178291200 |                          |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 15 | 1120 |  13650 |   425152 |   4084080 |    68456960 |     497125200 |     4811975168 |      24842737920 |      137602949120 |        456896294400 |        1322489954304 |         2318915727360 |           2643856588800 |            1307674368000 |                           |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 16 | 1360 |  17920 |   643552 |   6802432 |   133802240 |    1095311360 |    12765978368 |      76991602688 |      535086755840 |       2201647185920 |        8632830664704 |        21159839268864 |          39746508226560 |           42301705420800 |            20922789888000 |                            |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 17 | 1632 |  23120 |   948192 |  10940384 |   249443584 |    2274638080 |    31386271488 |     217021632256 |     1843944001536 |       9096474849280 |       46060832825344 |       146758121299968 |         399463775797248 |          675690639851520 |           740051782041600 |            355687428096000 |                             |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 18 | 1938 |  29376 |  1364352 |  17067456 |   446370496 |    4489984512 |    72329756928 |     564952886784 |     5750333382144 |      33190992027648 |      209797380112384 |       829094990856192 |        3041109959196672 |         7190347964350464 |         12902483299368960 |          13320932076748800 |            6402373705728000 |                              |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 19 | 2280 |  36822 |  1922496 |  25922688 |   770652160 |    8481039424 |   157639462656 |    1374265381632 |    16484438231040 |     109256334260736 |      840426228637696 |      3986150222135296 |       18793914785464320 |        57781089224736768 |        149519094622027776 |         245147182688010240 |          259500083163955200 |           121645100408832000 |                               |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 20 | 2660 |  45600 |  2658936 |  38449920 |  1289105920 |   15413043200 |   327260251136 |    3152789253120 |    43969745863680 |     329688764620800 |     3025552913852416 |     16808524572753920 |       98516919228170240 |       375878295709286400 |       1305140879116763136 |        2990381892440555520 |         5162443736924160000 |          5190001663279104000 |           2432902008176640000 |                                |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 21 | 3080 |  55860 |  3616536 |  55837656 |  2096554240 |   27071224320 |   650934158336 |    6872465273856 |   110178320179200 |     923364663137280 |     9949016970889216 |     63536611190900736 |      451495935256002560 |      2068855303791575040 |       9198585089011777536 |       27407958461452025856 |        67960463478175825920 |        108411318475407360000 |         111422936937037824000 |           51090942171709440000 |                                 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 22 | 3542 |  67760 |  4845456 |  79563792 |  3324982672 |   46124193280 |  1246501093376 |   14320551483392 |   261372556204032 |    2423923043942400 |    30263039559909376 |    218878373359562752 |     1849301381455818752 |      9932910575632056320 |      54713401772426428416 |      202368871958259105792 |       670935549630120394752 |       1495130196519868170240 |        2496471943395999744000 |         2451304612614832128000 |          1124000727777607680000 |                                 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 23 | 4048 |  81466 |  6403936 | 111445488 |  5154949888 |   76474601456 |  2307357538816 |   28669525147648 |   590745240322048 |    6011568792692736 |    86013269570584576 |    696049909877915648 |     6883503968725762048 |     42533931773483831296 |     283170345011963723776 |     1258408240765807853568 |      5325419604670079827968 |      15431517641492769079296 |       36884466463352967659520 |        57418854698107994112000 |         57504006817918746624000 |         25852016738884976640000 |                                  |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 24 | 4600 |  97152 |  8359120 | 153694464 |  7829641600 |  123718797312 |  4142747973760 |   55376580931584 |  1278813843865600 |   14177885767729152 |   230290920595210240 |   2064318469694029824 |    23588701805795737600 |    165204095249418289152 |    1303984707575575674880 |     6796088280287129370624 |     35527217383049468313600 |     127810070512081915871232 |      407240889859179425562624 |       885227195120471223828480 |       1435556519572510605312000 |       1380096163630049918976000 |         620448401733239439360000 |                                  |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 25 | 5200 | 115000 | 10787920 | 208978000 | 11672003200 |  195741040000 |  7235717906560 |  103568699344000 |  2663228367155200 |   31970346096640000 |   584738064788439040 |   5757273014880256000 |    75196663548146483200 |    589717545144893440000 |    5434087088811032903680 |    32599617689389391872000 |    205429424390227702579200 |     888180434576236707840000 |     3602492652661227322343424 |     10181022246479485639065600 |      23566236397584291201024000 |      35888912989312765132800000 |       35122852492484487413760000 |       15511210043330985984000000 |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 26 | 5850 | 135200 | 13777920 | 280485920 | 17105431200 |  303472083200 | 12324984946560 |  188128665570560 |  5356014550099200 |   69243937546035200 |  1415967063301079040 |  15203189684499415040 |   224885761935033139200 |   1955113252251808563200 |   20766743262578262343680 |   141286264309086855495680 |   1053019484314351891251200 |    5341165034145920267059200 |    26695183951643381726183424 |     93664808969191910380929024 |     288272814806050917816729600 |     612722146337191571226624000 |      968234590214616380866560000 |      913194164804596672757760000 |       403291461126605635584000000 |                                   |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 27 | 6552 | 157950 | 17428320 | 372003840 | 24678551040 |  461846642400 | 20518731192960 |  332774593557120 | 10435488520504320 |  144612392852678400 |  3285553377044029440 |  38231110709129134080 |   635371883416517345280 |   6071915572245894758400 |   73554801073377093550080 |   560702068089613083279360 |   4867748620659696989634560 |   28431526076487501063782400 |   170906639873583228936781824 |    720769966694371306606952448 |    2817222656974232498101813248 |    7783365999763374781051699200 |    17511732541318788803985408000 |    26142333935794642283397120000 |     25059533910850715800043520000 |     10888869450418352160768000000 |                                   |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 28 | 7308 | 183456 | 21850920 | 487992960 | 35094658560 |  690999429120 | 33450437180160 |  574524473402880 | 19753177140103680 |  292193678574120960 |  7334700376919024640 |  91995494557232824320 |  1705842983272133099520 |  17790412735662485667840 |  243568437096262146785280 |  2059534430054558619402240 |  20567406527168863321456640 |  136296961378471515709767680 |   966989370015233258722689024 |   4785385916460330410229891072 |   22998781724416629083096481792 |   78882234395278509946850770944 |   235445980534693282673432985600 |   490328511156926086511591424000 |    757044884113100699735162880000 |    701666949503820042401218560000 |    304888344611713860501504000000 |                                   |                                   |
| 1 | 29 | 8120 | 211932 | 27171144 | 633676680 | 49246454400 | 1017745098240 | 53489420624640 |  970062678224640 | 36414386868787200 |  572842137063006720 | 15808317055568532480 | 212706310930651714560 |  4373712325431885004800 |  49469446514891859886080 |  759490406430474231152640 |  7063484675791602256773120 |  80293904998751063284121600 |  596454789287897036322242560 |  4919601249990907214305951744 |  28042691730441764502957981696 |  161774973301766210979763322880 |  666964670008082243409797971968 |  2523030777997770071132105342976 |  6827933435506105197529556582400 |  14976571707663957208571314176000 |  21954301639279920292319723520000 |  20653229880222495090136842240000 |   8841761993739701954543616000000 |                                   |
| 1 | 30 | 8990 | 243600 | 33529104 | 815134320 | 68256754800 | 1477393632000 | 84021773571840 | 1604682618739200 | 65516267215526400 | 1092431606063616000 | 32993581167458734080 | 474249511667055974400 | 10754901653351436441600 | 131211369762956550144000 | 2243573801877230027735040 | 22784712192914226934579200 | 292198445272499130987315200 | 2408817149962531898523648000 | 22813244928627818303973228544 | 147588037499727216429178552320 | 1003055725215019146068502773760 | 4853249199052986329392899686400 | 22531970878240237373426044502016 | 75690923339933102133963160289280 | 219814574772847113134458011648000 | 449297151229918716257139425280000 | 679282279058620103859728547840000 | 619596896406674852704105267200000 | 265252859812191058636308480000000 |
+---+----+------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I thought I first spotted a pattern of writing $p_n'$ as a linear combination of $p_{n-1}$ and $p_{n-3}$, but it seems to fail (or I miscalculated). Undoubtedly you know of the appearance of Hermite polynomials in the solutions of the Schrödinger equation for a harmonic oscillator.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Indeed I do, but I haven't found a way to write my $p_n$'s in terms of Hermite polynomials. I may have missed something simple, though.

Comment: The pattern I had in mind survives in the weaker form
$$p_n'=np_{n-1}+\sum_{k>0}c_{n,k}p_{n-1-2k}.$$ 
Here $c_{n,k}$ are some positive integers, but don't ring a bell I'm afraid. I checked this up  for all $n\le9$. So $p_n'$ is a linear combination of lower degree polynomial **of a fixed parity**. This is not very informative, but does suggest that there is an even/odd game hidden.

Comment: Because the sequence of polynomials forms a basis of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, it is not at all suprising that $p_n'$ is some linear combination of the earlier ones. That half of the coefficients are zero OTOH may be...

Comment: Duh, that parity game follows immediately from the observation that the polynomial $p_n(x-1)$ is even when $n$ is even, and odd when $n$ is odd. Anyway, your list of coefficients will be only half as long, if you type down $p_n(x-1)$ instead of $p_n(x)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No need to apologize! In fact I hadn't noticed the symmetry of $p_n$ about $x=1$, which seems like a useful observation.

Comment: 1) You can obtain formulas for certain coefficients, for example $n(n+1)(n+2)/3$ for the third column of coefficients. 2) Of course, it is very visible that the constant coefficient is a factorial.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of Jyrki Lahtonen's comments, it turns out that these polynomials are a shifted version of the [Meixner polynomials](http://oeis.org/A060338) $M_n(x)$, defined by the recurrence relation

$$ M_{-1}(x) = 0 \qquad
   M_0(x) = 1 \qquad
   M_{n+1}(x) =xM_n(x)-n^2M_{n-1}(x) $$

In particular,

$$ p_n(x) = \frac{M_n(ix+i)}{i^n} $$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$ denotes the imaginary unit. A recurrence relation for $p_n$ easily follows:

$$ p_{-1}(x) = 0 \qquad
   p_0(x) = 1 \qquad
   p_{n+1}(x) = (x+1) p_n(x) + n^2 p_{n-1}(x) $$